# rename Renamed file already exist

Tags: vb.net-2010

i have a problem with renaming a duplicate file in a folder. How to skip it so that only the original file is renamed?

here is my code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(ListView1.Items(i).Text, TextBox7.Text)
next
```

Answer (score 1):

There is inherent mistake in the code. You are trying to give same name to multiple files. As per your code, each item of ListView1 obtained through `ListView1.Items(i).Text` will be renamed to text mentioned in `TextBox7.Text`.

The loop itself is wrong.